# Phantom doesn't open a page unless running through a proxy

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I need to scrape a website, decided to use Phantomjs. And because I love node I also thought it's ok to use Phantom npm package.

And did exactly as it's shown in readme:

```
phantom = require 'phantom'

phantom.create (ph)->
    ph.createPage (page)->
        page.open "http://stackoverflow.com", (status)->
            console.log "opened stackoverflow?", status
            page.evaluate (-> document.title), (result)->
                console.log "Page title is #{result}"
                ph.exit()
```

Now, strangely that didn't work first time I tried. I decided to pull up Charles and see if actually any requests are going out. And then suddenly it worked. Both messages show up in the console. Now I wonder, why it doesn't work without Charles running?